# How to remove HTML tags from JSON file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have problem with JSON file, I use Jbuilder gem in rails. Below it's my screenshot:
[image]

Do you know how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` class as explained here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

You may use `sanitize` or `strip_tags(html)` method to remove the tags.

I hope it helps :).

Answer (score 2):

Use strip_tags. For example:

```
json.meaning strip_tags(vocabulary.meaning)
```